# Updating the values of a column in one table with the values of a column in another table SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatable, inner-join

I have two separate tables in my database.  Table A has a column titled 'claimId', while Table B also has a column titled 'CLAIMID'.  The column in Table A is completely empty, and I need to fill it with all of the values that are already in the 'CLAIMID' column in Table B.  I've looked at multiple threads attempting to solve this issue, but to no avail.  When I run the query that I have written on Table A, it says "0 rows affected".  Is there something that I am missing when running this query?  I am fairly new to SQL, so I am still trying to understand everything with it.  I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, by the way.  Here is the query that I am trying to run below:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.claimId = b.CLAIMID
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
ON d.claimId = c.CLAIMID
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  How are you supposed to match rows in Table A to Table B?

Comment: I've actually figured out the answer and felt pretty dumb after doing so.  I posted the working query as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting this question I've solved the problem.  I feel kinda silly that I never thought about using `INSERT INTO`.  Like I said, I'm fairly new to this.  Here is the working query below:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (claimId)
SELECT CLAIMID
FROM TableB
```